# Multi Part Identifier Could Not Be Bound SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, sql-update, left-join

I know there are many questions out there with this issue, but I can't seem to find my issue out there. Probably because I am new at this. My issue is that it is giving me `multi part identifier could not be found` on `b.brandid`. Here is my code:

```
SELECT b.[brandid]

FROM [TempTable] a
left outer join [brandtable] b on (a.[brandlocation] = b.brandname)

UPDATE [MainTable]
SET [brandid] = b.brandid
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your update statement doesn't have a table in it named or aliased as "b". Not sure what the select statement has to do with your update here.

Comment: Are you trying to update the `MainTable.brandid` with the `brandid` from the first query?

Comment: what is the common column between maintable and brandtable

Comment: Yes I am trying to update MainTable.brandid with brandid

Comment: [Sql Basics Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm)

Comment: Thank you, the tutorial helped me out alot @MethodMan